# Kind of odd behavior in javascript involving lazyness

Tags: javascript, jquery

The weird "lazy" behavior in javascript. This one is working well:

```
$(document).on("change", "#dropdown-menu-category-chk", function(){
  $("#dropdown-menu-category input[type='checkbox']").prop('checked', this.checked);
 });

$(document).on("change", "#dropdown-menu-category2-chk", function(){
   $("#dropdown-menu-category2 input[type='checkbox']").prop('checked', this.checked);
 });

$(document).on("change", "#dropdown-menu-category3-chk", function(){
  $("#dropdown-menu-category3 input[type='checkbox']").prop('checked', this.checked);
 });

 // and so on....
```

But in this code the variable i == 5!

```
function setDropDowns(){
  var idList = ['category', 'category2', 'category3', 'category4', 'category5']
  for(var i = 0; i < idList.length; i++){
    $(document).on("change", "#dropdown-menu-"+idList[i]+"-chk", function(){
      $("#dropdown-menu-" +idList[i] +" input[type='checkbox']").prop('checked', this.checked);
        debugger; // i == 5; idList[i] === undefined
    });
  }
}
```

Even if I say

```
for(var i = 0; i < idList.length; i++){
  var id = dropDownCheckBoxItemList[i];
  $(document).on("change", "#dropdown-menu-"+id+"-chk", function(){
```

it won't work because `id` will be equal to `'category5'` when the code will be executed!

How do I make it work using loop? I don't want to break the rule of DRY.

Comment: Btw, the string `"#dropdown-menu-" + id + "-chk"` would get immediately evaluated, so that would actually work, albeit ugly ... but ofcourse the value of `id` would have the same issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to capture the value of `i` at each iteration of the loop. You can do this by introducing a new scope with an immediately invoked function expression:

```
for(var i = 0; i < idList.length; i++) {
    (function (i) {
        $(document).on("change", "#dropdown-menu-"+idList[i]+"-chk", function() {
            // etc...
        });
    }(i));
}
```

Comment: what do I read this statement? I know what it does thought. Is this an anonymous function or what?

Comment: @AlanDert - Yes, it's an anonymous function that executes itself immediately. You'll often hear this being referred to as a closure. This introduces a new scope, which maintains a reference to the outer lexical environment at the time of its creation. That means the anonymous function always has access to the state of `i` at the time it was created.

Comment: Why does it have the lazy behavior in my case?

Comment: Simply because when the event handler is executed your loop has already finished, so `i` has whatever its final value was.